# How to fulfill nil promise swift

Tags: ios, swift, promise, promisekit

I want to fulfill a promise with nil but I get error message that I cant here is my code

```
public static func getCurrentDevice() -> Promise<Device>{
    if let identity:[String:AnyObject] = auth?.get("identity") as! [String:AnyObject] {
        if let uuididentity = identity["uuid"]{
         return Promise { fulfill, reject in
            Alamofire.request( Router.getDevice(uuididentity as! String) )
                .responseObject { (response: Response<Device, NSError>) in
                    switch response.result{
                    case .Success(let data):
                        fulfill(data)
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        return reject(error)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        fulfill(nil)
    }
}
```

I get compiler error 
 **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Promise<*>' with an argument list of type '((*, _) -> _)'**

Answer (score 6):

If the promise doesn't return a value you should use `()` aka `Void`:

```
return Promise { fulfill, reject in
    fulfill(())
}
```

If this doesn't work (I didn't test it) you could try annotate it:

```
return Promise<()> { fulfill, reject in
    fulfill(())
}
```

(Note that `()` is the only value of type `()` aka `Void`)

Comment: thanks, I want to return explicit null can I do that?, I also try this and it doesn't work

Comment: `nil` is not a valid type, if you just want to return nothing without a specific type, use `()`. If you need an optional type, use `Int?` or whatever

Comment: I need to fulfill the promise and return nil, I did try the code you post and it doesn't work I have compiler issues. Any other idea how to do this?

Comment: I think I found a way just adding -> Promise<Device?> it works

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The question mark makes it for you in the return of the method.

```
public static func getCurrentDevice() -> Promise<Device?> {
        //... logic here
        let isDeviceEmpty: Bool

        if isDeviceEmpty {
            fulfill(nil)
        } else {
            fulfill(device)
        }
    }
```